# python pointcloud filtering with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, realsense

I'm trying to filter a point cloud with numpy.

i convert everything to a numpy array.

```
verts = np.asarray (points.get_vertices (2)). reshape (h, w, 3)
```

now I would e.g. like to only view values in a certain xmin, xmax range. or also xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax.

```
I tried the following for the x filter

verts = np.asarray(points.get_vertices(2)).reshape(h, w, 3)
texcoords = np.asarray(points.get_texture_coordinates(2))


xmin = -0.25
xmax = 0.25
ymin = 0.0
ymax = 1.0

inidx = np.all(np.logical_and(xmin <= verts, verts <= xmax), axis=0)
inbox = verts[inidx]
print(verts.length, inbox.length)
```

but already here I get an error message

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 212 but corresponding boolean dimension is 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By separating your different components with [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
>>> x, y, z = np.split(verts, 3, axis=-1)
```

You can combine conditions with the multiplication operator based on `x`, and `y`:

```
>>> mask = (xmin <= x)*(x <= xmax)*(ymin <= y)*(y <= ymax)
```

Then mask your `verts` array:

```
>>> verts_masked = verts[mask[..., 0]]
tensor([[ 0.1221,  0.2402,  0.7808],
        [ 0.1274,  0.1203, -0.9398],
        [ 0.0789,  0.8018, -0.7915],
        [ 0.1515,  0.3616, -0.2061],
        [ 0.2166,  0.3970,  0.4706],
        [ 0.2421,  0.0457,  0.1082],
        [ 0.0480,  0.9252,  0.2259],
        [ 0.2145,  0.5752, -0.3701],
        [-0.2099,  0.4220,  0.2342],
        [ 0.0949,  0.9467, -0.4768],
        [ 0.0746,  0.2131, -0.1160],
        [-0.2072,  0.4472, -0.3754],
        [-0.0994,  0.8972, -0.7704],
        [ 0.2424,  0.3210, -0.2291],
        [ 0.1093,  0.2599, -0.2868],
        [-0.2482,  0.6001, -0.3283]])
```

Additionally, if you are looking to mask `texcoords` with `mask` as well:

```
>>> textcoords_masked = textcoords[mask[..., 0]]
```

---

To sort the resulting arrays based on `z` you can use `np.argsort`:

```
>>> indices = np.argsort(verts_masked[:,-1])
```

Then get the filtered-sorted arrays for `verts` and `textcoords` as `verts_masked[indices]` and `textcoords_masked[indices]` respectively.

Comment: ok, the h,w shaped array is the problem. how can I combine two searches? how does numpy knows that it should search on the x, and not on x or z

Comment: @bluelemonade Apologies, my answer wasn't correct, I've edited it, see above.

Comment: great, thats reduces my poitcloud massiv. i can mak a masked array with verts2 = verts[mask[..., 0]]. can I reduce the texcoords with the same mask? firstsplit it an then mask it with the verts mask?

Comment: What's the shape of `texcoords`?

Comment: I think the first to of the verts, it's size is 2/3 of verts.

Comment: and how can I sort the final array to the z axis, split it again, and do a sort to get the lowest z value

Comment: thanks, works great, the texture throws an error, I think I'll be able to fix it on my own, and then I'll dig a little deeper into numpy.